# getting the html of div with runat=server using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I have a div having runat="server"

```
<div id="divError" runat="server" style="background-color:#FFF;">
</div>
```

and having the script part as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var IsError = $("#<%= divError.ClientID %>").html();
        debugger;
        if (IsError != null) {
            LogOutButtonClick();
        }
        else {
            if (parent.window.GetLoginCredentials) {
                parent.window.GetLoginCredentials(CheckLoginCredentials);
            }
        }
    });
```

But the problem is when I check the IsError, it is undefined
The reason is the $("#divError") is object[]
How to achieve this using javascript/jquery

Comment: Your `<div>` has no `runat="server"` attribute on it.

Comment: You can change your if condition to: `if(typeof IsError != 'undefined')`

Comment: @zgood   : is there any other method??

Comment: @Arvin What is the actual problem? Why do you care that IsError is undefined?  `if (undefined != null)` returns false, which I think would be what you want.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev divError is a div that displays error message,if login fails.The message is written from server side. All I want is to get the innerhtml using javascript/jquery and if it is null then there is no error so I can do the so and so code written in the if and else.

Comment: @Arvin yes but your code (the parts shown) still has no problem. You are only using `IsError` once and in that case, as I explained above, you would get the expected result. `if (null != null)` returns false just like `if (undefined != null)`. You haven't showed why it being undefined is causing you problems.

Comment: As it is a server control, since we have 'runat' somewhere in the ode its visiblity is made invisible usiong C#, thats the reason it is returning undefined

Comment: @Arvin Yes. So what? You aren't even using it. From what you have shown, it doesn't matter that it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It might be you need to look at [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`<div id="divError" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style="background-color:#FFF;"></div>`

I'm not sure if this works with a `<div>`, but the fact that you have `runat="server"` may allow this. Basically, setting it to "Static" means whatever ID you give the div, that will stick in the rendered HTMl, and not end up the usual ASP.NET weird ID.

You should then be able to do this:

`var IsError = $("div#divError").html();`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var IsError = $("#<%= divError.ClientID %>")[0];
    if (typeof IsError != 'undefined') {
        IsError = $("#<%= divError.ClientID %>").html();
        LogOutButtonClick();
    }
    else {
        if (parent.window.GetLoginCredentials) {
            parent.window.GetLoginCredentials(CheckLoginCredentials);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `runat="server"` is actually available in the DOM when you inspect your page then you can target it like this:

```
$('div[runat="server"]').someOtherjQueryFunction(); // target the div with runat="server"
```

If you are looking to get the value of `runat` then use this:

```
$('div#divError').attr('runat'); // returns the string value   server
```

I've never worked with ASP but I would imagine the parser strips out the `runat="server"` before sending it to the browser. If this is not true then hopefully one of the methods above will point you in the right direction.

What does `var IsError = $("#<%= divError.ClientID %>").html();` ultimately output in your browser?

**With the help of @MikeSmithDev this is my new recommendation**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // check if #divError exists
    if ($('div#divError').length > 0)
    {
        LogOutButtonClick();
    }
    else
    {
        if (parent.window.GetLoginCredentials)
        {
            parent.window.GetLoginCredentials(CheckLoginCredentials);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it is undefined while I debugg it using firebug

Comment: Ok, please read and answer the very **FIRST** and **LAST** lines I wrote.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `runat=server` does not get rendered to the DOM. The .ClientID gives him the `id` of the div as it is rendered to the DOM, since it likely will not be `divError`.