# js code busting when div is connected to server

Tags: javascript, c#, html, forms, server-side

I'm trying to create a website using ASP.NET where people can register and log in. I'm validating user's input using javascript and presenting them error messages accordingly. The problem is that when I press the submit button it just sends the form (the problem which occurs whenever you have a syntax problem). I have determined the code is faulty because it doesn't recognize the div it should change because it has the attribute `runat="server"`. For some reason the problem doesn't occur on the register page (the log in page is connected to a master page whilst the register page isn't if that matters). The site is connected to a datebase which saves the users in an SQL table.

Please try to explain in simple terms since I am a newbie (been coding for less than a year).

```
<head runat="server">
  <title>log in</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkForm(){
      var username = document.getElementById("usernameInput").value;
      if (username.length < 6) {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "<br />Username is invalid";
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form2" method="post" runat="server" onsubmit="return 
checkForm();">
    <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:left">
      Username:
      <br />
      <input type="text" name="usernameInput" id="usernameInput"/> 
      <div runat="server" id="errorMessage" name="errorMessage" style="display:none"></div>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

This is the code with mostly the essentials, the line calling for .innerHTML doesn't recognize the div when it has the `runat="server"` attribute (the code works when I delete it). Again, for some reason the code seems to work on the register page.

I use C# in order to work on the server side and to present error messages regarding whether or not the log in matched any of the users existing, that's why I need the `runat="server"` part.

Edit: I have applied the 1st solution presented in the comments which was adding this attribute `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the div tag. It is now working.

Comment: See this link. It might be of some help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707233/getting-the-html-of-div-with-runat-server-using-jquery-javascript